# Easy cross-platform python way of colouring text in the command line/shell

Tags: python, command-line, cross-platform

Bascially, I want an easy(ish), cross-platform way of colouring text in the command line/shell.

I would really like this to not involve importing a module, but because cross-platform support is pretty complicated, I know it will probably have to.

I don't need it to be too elaborate though, just a few basic colours will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing [ANSI excape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) doesn't require anything fancy and should be fairly easy.

[Here](http://nezzen.net/2008/06/23/colored-text-in-python-using-ansi-escape-sequences/) is a basic exaple that show how it can be done manually.*

Or you could also have a look of libraries like [termcolor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) or [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) for reference.

*edit: just seen that this example isn't really fully functional. to make it work `33[` has to be replaced with `\033[`

Comment: Yeah, just tested it and it didn't work. Changing the `33[`s didn't work either though.

Comment: That is probably because I'm using windows.

Comment: I decided to use Colorama, and it's lovely... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism for coloring terminal output is pretty universal. It's done by echoing escape commands into the output stream.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

The real key is determining whether the terminal you're looking at *supports* coloring. If, for example, output is being redirected to a file, then the escape sequences will just clutter your output stream, since you're probably eventually be reading the file with a text editor.

Determining the capabilities of your terminal window is generally handled through something called "termcap", and there are several libraries for that purpose, with that exact name. This is also often rolled into more capable libraries, like curses.

And, it turns out, you're in luck: http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a module if you want something cross-platform / slightly complicated.

I'd recommend using pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama, which is cross-platform.